# Xcode stuck on "Your Application is Being Uploaded"?

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

I am trying to upload an iOS application to the App Store on Xcode, but for some reason after it passes validation the application is stuck on "Your Application is Being Uploaded". It's only 1.7mb, and there are no errors in the project. I've cleaned, analysed, re-archived, restarted the application, seemingly everything. But for some reason it just won't uploaded. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried deleting derived data? Go to "Organizer->Projects", click on the project in question then click on the "Delete..." button next to Derived Data. Also, try restarting the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Application Loader instead.

Not the most well-named app, I know, but it still works.